# Formatting dynamic html content...ex: {{foobar.data}}

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js, formatting

I have some dynamic HTML content:  `<td> {{ hash2.transactions}} </td>` in a Vue component. Ive seen them called so many things too...handlebars, computed properties, dynamic content...maybe someone could kindly tell me also what the most correct name for them is?

Here is the rendered data itself raw from the API: `[["3h05YxcE9lmZYNQ7iZVC8ZehEjR3iauz",["Movement Detected"]]]`

Basically I wanted to show only the `Movement Detected` bit.

**What I tried**

I started by converting to a string:  `{{ hash2.transactions.toString() }}` which removed the array braces.

Then I tried rendering by the character numbers: `{{ hash2.transactions.toString()[34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39] }}`

The problem with the above attempt was that this would display only the 39th character, ignoring the preceding characters.

So I tried concatenation , which seemed to work, but obviously this is a bit verbose and probably frowned upon.

`<td> {{ hash2.transactions.toString()[33] + hash2.transactions.toString()[34] + hash2.transactions.toString()[35] + hash2.transactions.toString()[36] + hash2.transactions.toString[37] + hash2.transactions.toString[38] hash2.transactions.toString[39] }} </td>`

Surely there is a more dignified way to do this? Hoping someone could weigh in and enlighten me a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood is the you want to display the "movment detected" bit only
And the `hash2.transaction` returns this
`[["3h05YxcE9lmZYNQ7iZVC8ZehEjR3iauz",["Movement Detected"]]]` as a string
Well, That looks like its a JSON for me
You could do 
`JSON.parse(hash2.transaction)[0][1][0];`
That must return the "movment detected" string 
If it exists if not it will return an error

You could do something like this

```
<td> {{ JSON.parse(hash2.transaction)[0][1][0]; }} </td>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, this does make sense what youre saying but Im getting an error: ```Unexpected token 'h' at position 1 at JSON parse```.  Ill keep playing around with it

Comment: Make sure your `hash2.transaction` is returning a string like `[["3h05YxcE9lmZYNQ7iZVC8ZehEjR3iauz",["Movement Detected"]]]` + make sure the that you escape all the double quotes in the string with the `replace() ` if you need help with that ask

Comment: Worked when leaving out JSON.parse -> ```hash2.transaction[0][1][0]``` Thanks again :)

Comment: Great to Hear!! however, that means that `hash2.transaction` is the object itself, not a JSON string that's why it worked when you left `JSON.parse()`.